# How do I find the id of the current user that is "logged in" with a jwt? I am trying to make a GET request and filter by specific id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, fetch

This the endpoint in my api that I am trying to access

```
router.get('/:id', [jsonParser, jwtAuth], (req, res) => {
return Teams.find().sort({creator: req.params.id})
    .then(teams => res.status(200).json(teams))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal server error'}));
});
```

The fetch will probably look something like this?

```
function viewProfile() {
const base = '/api/teams/';
const id = idFromJwt;
const url = base + id;

return fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => {
//takes response and modifies DOM
    populateProfile(response);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: What are you using on the server there? What is `jwtAuth`? Where is `router` coming from?

Comment: The second argument needs to be a __function__. Like this `(req, res, next) => { // }`

Comment: How you generate the jwt token? You can add the current logged in user data in the token. When You Authenticate user using the token you can retrieve the current user object.

Comment: jwtAuth is a middlware that verifies if I have a valid token. I guess I should mention I have my jwt stored in local storage when initialing logging in.

Comment: The token in my local storage is signed with a user object containing the id. I guess I'm asking how can I pull the id from the jwt that's in local storage. Could I send the id along with the jwt in the server response when signing in and store the id in local storage too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, assuming you're using `ExpressJS` I do suggest leveraging [`express-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) middleware to handle requests authentication and issuing new Tokens.

What you need to bear in mind is that, you need to include the `userId` when you authenticate the user in the JWT payload in order to be able to retrieve it from the payload afterwards.

When user is authenticated, you have to store the token in the state of your application or in the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

In case you want to decode the token on the front-end side and then send it to the API, you can use a simple module called [`jwt-decode`](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to achieve that:

```
const jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode");
const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token"); // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWQiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9.gHqSxzWpdOUL1nRAqUJg2CtjsEZZi8FLikD41i639zY
const tokenPayload = jwtDecode(token).id; // "123456789"
```

Please bear in mind that in case you decided to use `express-jwt` you need to also send the token in the headers of the request as `authorization` to authenticate.
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I tried this but got 'ReferenceError: window is not defined'. I'm also trying to get the information of the user logged in. I've managed to do it before with req.headers.authorization but this time I'm not using req, so I need another way to retrieve the headers.